# Почему в Safari съезжает курсор с поля формы?

Tags: css, safari

Проблема в следующем, съезжает курсор с полей формы в браузере Safari как решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код форм

```html
<div class="EmbedForm" id="nZDxc3oo" data-key-form="nZDxc3oo">
  <style>
    #box_form_nZDxc3oo {}
    
    input.input_form_nZDxc3oo {
      font-size: 14px;
      width: 100%;
      color: #8e8d8d;
      font-family: Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
      border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 4px #f1f1f1;
      padding: 21px 15px 20px 15px;
      height: 17px;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .send-bottom-nZDxc3oo {
      width: inherit;
      padding: 10px 10px;
      color: #fff !important;
      font: 18px/22px Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 700;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      background: #FF6347;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 3px;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      outline: 0;
    }
    
    .send-bottom-nZDxc3oo:hover {
      color: #ffffff;
      background: #06a9ef;
      border-color: #0586bd;
    }
    
    #text_after_send_form_nZDxc3oo {
      display: none;
      margin-top: 40px;
      color: #333;
      text-align: center;
      font: 18px/22px Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="box_form_nZDxc3oo">
    <div class="forms-flexbox vertikal content_nZDxc3oo" id="form_nZDxc3oo">
      <div class="forms-column-flexbox el-form-nZDxc3oo"><input id="contact_name_nZDxc3oo" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ваше Имя" class="input_form_nZDxc3oo user"></div>
      <div class="forms-column-flexbox el-form-nZDxc3oo"><input id="contact_phone_nZDxc3oo" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Ваш Телефон" class="input_form_nZDxc3oo user"></div>

      <div class="forms-column-flexbox el-form-nZDxc3oo">
        <div class="send-bottom send-bottom-nZDxc3oo" id="send-bottom" data-key-form="nZDxc3oo" data-check-email="" data-encoding-form="1" data-id-form-key="8379" [![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1] data-ya-metrik-id="0" data-ya-metrik-goals="">Отправить
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="text_after_send_form_nZDxc3oo">Спасибо, Ваша заявка получена! С вами свяжутся через 5 минут!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-fix-the-ios-11-input-element-in-fixed-modals-bug-aaf66c7ba3f8

Comment: @St1myL не понял я как в моем примере это поправить.